# Python, pandas print most frequent 1-1000 from csv

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, frequency

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import csv
data1=pd.read_csv('11-01 412-605.csv', low_memory=False)
d412=pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['size', 'price',  'date'])

new_df = pd.value_counts(d412['size']).reset_index()
new_df.columns = ['size', 'frequency']
print (new_df)


export_csv = new_df.to_csv ('empty.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Which outputs:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfcDD.jpg)
However, I want to print out the values that only have a count of 1-1000. How do I do that because right now it prints out all the values.
I tried:

```
new_df = pd.value_counts(d412['size']<1000).reset_index()
```

But that does not work as it prints out true or false for all values less than 1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
print(new_df.loc[df_new['frequency']<1000,:])
```

if i misunderstood the columns of the count please substitute 'frequency' with 'size'

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

As per the reference of [Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), it's clear **value_counts() doesn't allow filtering the values**. You can filter the data using [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) in a later step, as it's mentioned by others too. So, the following code shall work:

```py
new_df = pd.value_counts(d412['size']).reset_index()
new_df.columns = ['size', 'frequency']
print(new_df.loc[new_df['frequency'] <= 1000])
```